# T-SQL : Loop within CASE Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, loops, case

I need to create a new column where the following is respected:

- If **all** `Order_ID` within **one** `ID` have a `Approved` flag of **1** and `Denied` flag of **0**, Then flag it as  ***Approved***. (Example : `ID 1`)
- If **all** `Order_ID` within **one** `ID` have a `Approved` flag of **0** and `Denied` flag of **1**, Then flag it as  ***Denied***. (Example : `ID 2`)
- If **some** `Order_ID` within **one** `ID` have a `Approved` flag of **1** and `Denied` flag of **0** and the others are either with an `Approved` flag of **0** and `Denied` flag of **1** or an `Approved` flag of **0** and `Denied` flag of **0**, Then flag it as  ***Partially approved***. (Example : `ID 3` and `6`)
- If **any** `Order_ID` within **one** `ID` have a `Approved` flag of **1** and `Denied` flag of **1** regardless of the other `Order_ID` within the `ID` , Then flag it as  ***Error***.  (Example : `ID 4`)
- If **all** `Order_ID` within **one** `ID` have a `Approved` flag of **0** and `Denied` flag of **0**, Then flag it as  ***Pending Approval***.  (Example : `ID 5`)

This is a simplified table I am using as an example:

```
 **ID       Order_ID   Approved   Denied
   1          101         1         0
   2          201         0         1
   2          202         0         1
   1          102         1         0
   4          401         0         1
   3          301         0         1
   6          601         0         1
   1          103         1         0
   3          302         1         0
   3          303         0         0
   5          501         0         0
   4          402         1         0
   6          602         1         0
   5          502         0         0
   4          403         1         1
   5          503         0         0
```

and this is the result I expect :

```
 **Id       Order_ID   Approved   Denied   Approval_status 
   1          101         1         0        Approved
   2          201         0         1         Denied
   2          202         0         1         Denied
   1          102         1         0        Approved
   4          401         0         1         Error
   3          301         0         1    Partially approved
   6          601         0         1    Partially approved
   1          103         1         0        Approved
   3          302         1         0    Partially approved
   3          303         0         0    Partially approved
   5          501         0         0     Pending Approval
   4          402         1         0        Error
   6          602         1         0    Partially approved
   5          502         0         0     Pending Approval
   4          403         1         1        Error
   5          503         0         0     Pending Approval
```

Thank you much in advance !!  I am mainly confused of how to loop within one `ID` in a CASE statement.

Comment: Don't use a loop.  Create the column then do 3 or 4 updates to build your business rules in the correct order.  **NO LOOPS IN SQL!**

Comment: @hogan how do I stay within one ID only ?

Comment: You don't, working with sets means that you apply a change to all IDs that meet a requirement. for example if you group by id then you can compare the count(*) to the sum(*) to see if a field is 1 for every item.

Comment: wouldn't be better you sort your sample data before posting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take back my comment above.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS NumberOfOrder
        , SUM(Approved) AS NumberOfApproved
        , SUM(Denied) AS NumberOfDenied
        , SUM(IIF(Approved=1 AND Denied=1,1,0)) AS NumberOfError
        , ID
    FROM
        TestTable T1
    GROUP BY
        T1.ID
)
SELECT
    T2.*
    , CASE
        WHEN CTE.NumberOfError > 0 THEN 'Error'
        WHEN CTE.NumberOfApproved=CTE.NumberOfOrder THEN 'Approved'
        WHEN CTE.NumberOfDenied=CTE.NumberOfOrder THEN 'Denied'
        WHEN CTE.NumberOfApproved>0 OR CTE.NumberOfDenied > 0 THEN 'Partially Approved'
        ELSE 'Pending Approval'
    END AS Approval_Status
FROM
    TestTable T2
    JOIN CTE ON T2.ID=CTE.ID
```